# Problems setting a ReactNative state

Tags: react-native

I made an API with some for a "todo" application
But when I take that data from the water the first time I give a console.log () I will have an empty object and only after the data object
When I want to display them, nothing appears, but when I had them without water before, everything was ok
That's how I take the data

```js
const [todos, setTodos] = useState({});

React.useEffect(() => {
  axios.get('http://localhost:8000/app/todo-data/').then((response) => {
    setTodos(JSON.stringify(response.data));
  });
}, []);
```

My view

```js
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Header />
    <View style={styles.header}>
      <View style={styles.content}>
        <View style={styles.list}>
          <FlatList
            data={todos}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <TodoItem item={item} pressHandler={pressHandler} />
            )}></FlatList>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  </View>
);
```

And todo item view

```js
export default function TodoItem({ item, pressHandler }) {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => {
        pressHandler(item.id);
      }}>
      <Text style={styles.item}>{item.item}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

Data from API

```json
[
  { id: 1, item: 'dasdasdasdsa', satisfied: false },
  { id: 2, item: 'To make a tea', satisfied: false },
  { id: 3, item: 'To make a sandwich', satisfied: false },
  { id: 4, item: 'To make a cake', satisfied: false },
  { id: 5, item: 'To make a cake', satisfied: false },
  { id: 6, item: 'To make a cake', satisfied: false },
  { id: 7, item: 'To make a cake', satisfied: false },
  { id: 8, item: 'To make a cake', satisfied: false },
];
```

Todo state without API

```js
/*const [todos, setTodos] = useState([
    { item: 'buy coffee', id: '1'},
    { item: 'buy tea', id: '2'},
    { item: 'buy hamburger', id: '3'},
    { item: 'buy banana', id: '4'},
  ]);*/
```

When I wasn't using water data, everything was ok ...
Do you know what the main problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your problem appears because of async flow of JavaScript. I mean, you said that when you try to console.log() your object from axios response, at first time you see empty object and later your data appears. Try this solution:

```js
const [todos, setTodos] = useState({});
const getData = async () => {
  const data = await axios
    .get('http://localhost:8000/app/todo-data/')
    .then((response) => JSON.stringify(response.data));
  setTodos(data);
};

React.useEffect(() => {
  getData();
}, []);
```

You can find more information in this [article](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-fetch-async-await/)